# What does it mean $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$ in the book of R. Schilling (Brownian motion)?

Tags: probability, notation, conditional-expectation

In a book, there are the following notations that I don't understand.

know conditional expectation, but here I don't get what $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$ means. Is it $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X]$ or $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X=x]$ ?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. It means that for every Borel subset $B$ of $\mathbb R^d$, $X^{-1}(B):=\{\omega,X(\omega)\in B\}$ belongs to $\mathcal X$.
2. We can define a function $f\colon\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=\mathbb E\left[\Phi\left(x,Y\right)\right]$ and the notation $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$ means that for each fixed $\omega$, we evaluate $f$ at $X(\omega)$.

Comment: So in fact $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$ is just $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X=x]$, right ?

Comment: It seems that the first denotes really the conditional expectation of $\Phi(X,Y)$ with respect to $\mathcal X$ while the second denotes the function $f$ in the answer.

Comment: Sorry, but at the end, it's ambigus... thoses notation looks weird. So for you $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$ is the conditional expectation $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid \mathcal X]$ or is it $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)\mid X=x]$ I don't get what you mean with "first one is..." and "second one is..." Could you be more precise please ? (why don't they use normal notation ???)

Comment: By "the first one", I mean $\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}$. By "the second one", I mean $\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X=x]$. For your last question I have unfortunately no answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of these notation, but it looks that if $f(x)=\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X=x]$ then  $$\mathbb E[\Phi(x,Y)]|_{x=X}=f(X)=:\mathbb E[\Phi(X,Y)\mid X].$$